# How to return a vector of codes for each level of a variable in R?

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, subset

I have a `data frame` with several diagnosis codes for each health condition (one code per row). I need to get a `vector` of codes for each condition, and the vector needs to be named after each condition.

```
Condition <- as.character(c("COPD", "COPD", "COPD", "COPD", "HIV", "HIV", "HIV", "Sepsis", "Sepsis", "Sepsis", "Sepsis", "Sepsis"))
Code <- as.character(c("6A61.00", "8BPT.00", "8BPT000", "8BPT100", "E2E0.00", "E2E0100", "E2E0z00", "E2E1.00", "E2E2.00", "E2Ey.00", "E2Ez.00", "Eu84400"))
df <- data.frame(Condition, Code)

df
   Condition    Code
1       COPD 6A61.00
2       COPD 8BPT.00
3       COPD 8BPT000
4       COPD 8BPT100
5        HIV E2E0.00
6        HIV E2E0100
7        HIV E2E0z00
8     Sepsis E2E1.00
9     Sepsis E2E2.00
10    Sepsis E2Ey.00
11    Sepsis E2Ez.00
12    Sepsis Eu84400
```

What I expect to get:

```
> COPD
[1] "6A61.00" "8BPT.00" "8BPT000" "8BPT100"
> HIV
[1] "E2E0.00" "E2E0100" "E2E0z00"
> Sepsis
[1] "E2E1.00" "E2E2.00" "E2Ey.00" "E2Ez.00" "Eu84400"
```

However, I don't want to have to create a `vector` for each condition in an individual piece of code, like this:

```
COPD <- df$Code[which(df$Condition=="COPD")]
HIV <- df$Code[which(df$Condition=="HIV")]
Sepsis <- df$Code[which(df$Condition=="Sepsis")]
```

Is there a better way of optimizing a piece of code to get one vector of codes for each condition at once? (I have ~300 conditions).

Additionally, I don't want the vector to return as a `factor`, like as it is happening:

```
> COPD
[1] 6A61.00 8BPT.00 8BPT000 8BPT100
12 Levels: 6A61.00 8BPT.00 8BPT000 8BPT100 E2E0.00 E2E0100 E2E0z00 E2E1.00 ... Eu84400
> HIV
[1] E2E0.00 E2E0100 E2E0z00
12 Levels: 6A61.00 8BPT.00 8BPT000 8BPT100 E2E0.00 E2E0100 E2E0z00 E2E1.00 ... Eu84400
> Sepsis
[1] E2E1.00 E2E2.00 E2Ey.00 E2Ez.00 Eu84400
12 Levels: 6A61.00 8BPT.00 8BPT000 8BPT100 E2E0.00 E2E0100 E2E0z00 E2E1.00 ... Eu84400
```

I appreciate your help on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -

```
list2env(split(as.character(df$Code), df$Condition), .GlobalEnv)

COPD
#[1] "6A61.00" "8BPT.00" "8BPT000" "8BPT100"

HIV
#[1] "E2E0.00" "E2E0100" "E2E0z00"

Sepsis
#[1] "E2E1.00" "E2E2.00" "E2Ey.00" "E2Ez.00" "Eu84400"
```

However, it is not considered a good practice to create so many independent vectors in global environment. They are difficult to manage. It is better to keep them in list itself.

Answer (score 2):

We may do this in `base R` with `unstack`

```
list2env(unstack(df, Code ~ Condition), .GlobalEnv)
```

-checking for objects

```
> COPD
[1] "6A61.00" "8BPT.00" "8BPT000" "8BPT100"
> HIV
[1] "E2E0.00" "E2E0100" "E2E0z00"
> Sepsis
[1] "E2E1.00" "E2E2.00" "E2Ey.00" "E2Ez.00" "Eu84400"
```